# 404 Redirect not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I'm type to make a plugin which shows a page instead of sending a 404 page when on a page that doesn't exist

I know I can edit to 404.php file to do this but i need to fit this in a plugin.

If I remove the if statement then its works on all pages which isn't what I want.
So i put the if(is_404()) statement in but it doesn't seem to work at all now...

```
    function da_404_redirect()
    {
      if(is_404())
      {      
        query_posts('page_id=2');
        status_header( "200" );
      }
    }
    add_action('init','da_404_redirect');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect, don't hook on `init`, especially if you use conditional tag like is_404(). Any conditional tag will still return `false` in `init`.

USE: `template_redirect` instead or `pre_get_post` if you need to change something on the `WP_Query`

Comment: Thanks I used template redirect which works.....  Does anyone have a good resource for hooks....

Comment: You're welcome. I don't have that recourse. I usually jump into wp core files to find any.

Answer (score 2):

Your action hook may be too soon in the wordpress cycle to know if it is a 404. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init.  Try using a later action hook.

Comment: Thanks, @editor, I knew it was the wrong action he was hooking into but, I didn't know the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

As Nick says above you might be hooking into a late-firing event. In my experience, [template_redirect](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/template_redirect) is the best option.